# Django: Where to store a lot of methods called on model.save()?

Tags: python, django

I am using Django 1.9. I have a model that represents the number of patients at a doctor's practice in a given month, broken down by age and sex:

```
class PracticeList(models.Model):
    practice = models.ForeignKey(Practice)
    date = models.DateField()
    male_0_4 = models.IntegerField()
    female_0_4 = models.IntegerField()
    male_5_14 = models.IntegerField()
    female_5_14 = models.IntegerField() 
    ... etc
    total_list_size = models.IntegerField()
    prescribing_needs = JSONField(null=True, blank=True)
```

I use the value of the integer fields to drive various measures adjusted for age and sex. There are a large and unpredictable number of these, hence using a JSONField for `prescribing_needs`. I initially calculated and set these on the model's `save` method:

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.total_list_size = self.male_0_4 + self.female_0_4 + ....
        antibiotics = 1.2 * self.male_0_4 + 1.1 * self.female_0_4 + ...
        # plus 40-50 other calculations
        self.prescribing_needs = {
            'antibiotics': antibiotics ...
        }
        super(PracticeList, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

This worked, but made my models file unmanageably long. So my question is quite simple: **What is the Django Way to split out the method to calculate all these measures on `save`?**

Right now I've simply created a new file called `model_calculations.py` in the same directory as `models.py`:

```
def set_prescribing_needs(c):
    antibiotics = 1.1 * c.male_0_4 + 1.1 * female_0_4 ...
    prescribing_needs = {
        'antibiotics': antibiotics
    }
    return prescribing_needs
```

And I just import this file into `models.py` and do:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.prescribing_needs = model_calculations.set_prescribing_needs(self)
    super(PracticeList, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Is this OK, or is there a more Djangoish place to store these methods?

Comment: Be careful with overriding model.save. There are some situations where this method doesn't get called, like on some bulk operations (I remember right now bulk_create or queryset.update). The safer (but uglier) option is to put a receiver on the pre_save signal for the model.

Comment: I agree with @dyeray, don't override `save()` function for your models, it's very easily messed up with the built in logic django has. Use `pre_save` signal as much as possible: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/signals/#pre-save

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is an OK way to do it and is the Django way of doing it. There are two things I would look for.

When you have some functions that are used in multiple apps, put those functions in a `main/model_calculations.py`, `core/model_calculations.py`, or whatever app you have that is shared across your whole project.

If you find that some of these functions are used outside of your models, I would put them in a `utils.py` file.

As long as these functions are used just in a single app, and only used in models, where you're currently storing them is fine.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Yes, they are single-app only right now. Much appreciated!